# is there a way to emulate git show in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I frequently use $ git show commitid to see what changes a person did. For e.g. -

```
┌─[shirish@debian] - [~/games/libcpuid] - [10029]
└─[$] git show b5bd535

commit b5bd5355829dcd123fba20a3c1d14f2bc139dc43
Author: eloaders <eloaders@linux.pl>
Date:   Mon Oct 3 20:10:02 2016 +0200

Fix #72

let libcpuid 0.4.0 and brethen conflict with libcpuid 0.3.0 and its
brethen

diff --git a/debian/control b/debian/control
index ba71f44..b70c5da 100644
--- a/debian/control
+++ b/debian/control
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@ Homepage: https://github.com/anrieff/libcpuid
 Package: libcpuid14
 Architecture: amd64 i386
 Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, ${misc:Pre-Depends}
-Replaces: libcpuid11

+Replaces: libcpuid11, libcpuid13
 Description: small C library for x86/x86_64 CPU detection and feature extraction
```

This is from https://github.com/anrieff/libcpuid but that's not the actual question. Is there a similar way to use mercurial having colored diffs and all ? I tried $hg show changeset id but got nowhere :(

Comment: `hg export -r revnum`, perhaps? And have you enabled the color extension?

Comment: @FaheemMitha - 
      " 'hg export' may generate unexpected diff output for merge changesets, as it will compare the merge changeset against its first parent only."

Comment: have enabled the color extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have Color Extension enabled

Use something like `hg log -r NNN -v -p -g` (can't show colored chunks, but they *are* here)

```
changeset:   7:32bbc6bc3867
user:        AL <lazybadger@*>
date:        Tue Nov 20 03:51:53 2012 +0600
files:       404.php
description:
Localization of page


diff --git a/404.php b/404.php
--- a/404.php
+++ b/404.php
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 <?php get_header(); ?>

   <article class="noposts">
-       <h2>404 - Content Not Found</h2>
-       <p>We don't seem to be able to find the content you have requested - why not try a search below?</p>
+       <h2><?php _e('404 - Content Not Found','fiver' ); ?></h2>
+       <p><?php _e('We don&rsquo;t seem to be able to find the content you have requested - why not try a search below?','fiver' ); ?></p>
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
   </article>
```

If you'll want to change default output - just write own style and add `-T stylename` to log options

**Note**

Options used:

- `-r` define the scope of changesets to show (it can be single changeset or revset)
- `-v` (optional) verbose output: slightly change format of default output and add string with files, affected in each changeset (has no analogues in default `git show`)
- `-p` append diff of changes to log-output
- `-g` emit the above diff in "extended Git format" (because in `git show` diff is always in Git-format)

Comment: can you improve your answer by giving the what each switch does , for e.g. I see that  - r = commit message with user, date and whatever details (no code) , -v = verbose - it lists files which have changed , -p = difference between last changeset and this changeset , dunno what does -g bring in ? Also saw https://slaptijack.com/software/git-show-in-hg.html . Actually that link fixed it.

Comment: @shirish - added (and fixed some *your* mistakes in guessing)

Comment: actually saw that `hg export` also does that but with 'hg export revid` that does the trick. But this means that you have to use the  `hg log | less` to know commit/revid . For the most recent one just running `hg export` is good enough. Still full marks for trying.

Comment: @shirish - if you want to know|have cset-id, you can use shortest template instead of default: `hg log -T "{node|short}\n"` or `"{rev}\n"`